# 301 redirect url with parameters to non-trailing slash url (htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, slash, trailing

Hi we’re using wordpress in apache server.

We want to 301 redirect our specific path with trailing slash to non trailing slash.

Example:

https://www.example.com/action/villa/?city=Ankara&area=etimesgut/

to

https://www.example.com/action/villa/?city=Ankara&area=etimesgut

How can we make that with using htaccess?

I have searched on site but i cant find content redirect urls like that with htaccess.

Thank you for your help

Comment: How did you get first URL with trailing slash in query string?

Answer (score 0):

To remove your trailing slash, add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: But we want to redirect path just like in example not all urls :/